# New banner "Want to improve this post?"?

Tags: support, questions

Just stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378839/how-to-solve-invalid-credentials-problem-in-bitbucket) (audit) question, that presents a banner like this:

> **Want to improve this post?** Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

Screenshot:

> [image: Want to improve this post? Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.]

Is this a new kind of banner? I didn't see it before. Or did it replace the older "Need at least 10 reputation to answer this"?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not new, it's just relatively seldom used compared to a lot of the other [post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172592) like Bounties and the "Historical significance" post notice.

This notice in particular is the "Needs detailed answers" post notice. It's more often placed on answers which are insubstantial (to suggest improving the answer), [such as this one (from 2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19478850/3270037), but can also be applied to questions.

---

You can find these posts more easily in the [Noticed tab](https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed) of the annotated posts page.

Comment: Interesting that the banner you linked says "Provide detailed answers to this question", while the banner was added to an answer. Though the banner makes sense on an answer too if we take into consideration its full text.

Comment: Also curious how this banner ends up being added. There are lots of posts that should deserve it.

Comment: @Cristik Mods can add it, check the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71378839/timeline#history_c2c76c0a-4e79-4792-a9bd-265a51d0def1) or [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71378839/revisions) of the post in your question.

Comment: @Cristik There are two banners. One for questions and one for answers. This one should only be used on questions. We can't enforce that in the system (or we couldn't when it was built) so it occasionally gets misused. I've switched it to the answer-specific post notice. That said, after this long, the answer may just need someone else to do something about it - either deleting or editing or whatever.

Comment: But it is so random that it even exists. We make such a point out of the site being community curated and that actual diamond mods should not be responsible for it - there is too much content and only a handful of mods after all. And then there is this feature... made for mods to help curate the content. And with with the mountain of content there is, this can only be used very inconsistently.

Comment: Putting these banners on answers seems particularly pointless. Mods on smaller sites use them more than SO does. I prefer to just delete the post until it has been modified to meet our minimum expectations.